# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read some values from the user and based on those values i would like to assign a unique value to another variable(int wbn) in the same model class
the code is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace testmvc.Models
{
    public class wobbly_biz
    {
        //wob_code_logic wcl = new wob_code_logic();
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }

        public static int wob_gen(int size,int order)
        {
            if (size == 3)
            {
                if (order == 1) { return 101; }
                if (order == 2) { return 121; }
                if (order==10) { return 202; }
            }
            return 999; }


            public int wbn = wob_gen(size, order);


    }

}
```

Actually i am trying to implement some programming logic over there to assign a value to int wbn, need help please.

Comment: Tried, but not working...
Be it a simple edit or to change the entire path of writing method...give me away of implementing a logic to assign a new value to int wbn...based on the size and order values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public int wbn
{
    get
    {
        return wob_gen(size, order);
    }
}
```

This way, you update `size` or `order`, next time you get `wbn` it will recalculate the value through `wob_gen`.